# Python: RE vs. Query

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am building a website using Django, and this website uses blocks which are enabled for a certain page.

Right now I use a textfield containing paths were a block is enabled. When a page is requested, Django retrieves all blocks from database and does re.search on the TextField.

However, I was wondering if it is not a better idea to use a separate DB table for block/paths, were each row contains a single path and reference to a block, in terms of overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly familiar with Django, but if I am understanding the situation correctly, you should use a table.

In fact this is exactly the kind of use that DB software is designed and optimized for.

**No worries.  It will actually be faster.**

By doing the search yourself, you are trying to implement part of the DB logic on your own.  Fun, certainly, but not so fast.  :)

Here are some nice links on designing a database:

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form

Hope this helps. Good luck.  **:-)**

Answer (score 2):

A seperate DB table is definitely the "right" way to do it, because mysql has to send all the data from your TEXT fields every time you query. As you add more rows and the TEXT fields get bigger, you'll start to notice performance issues and eventually crash the server. Also, you'll be able to use VARCHAR and add a unique index to the paths, making lookups lightning fast.